# ApplicationSettingsBase and XmlSerialization not working without using csc.exe on a Merged executable

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I try to save some application data using ApplicationSettingsBase class's Save method. I have a net 2.0 exe (BugTest.exe) and a net 2.0  dll (MyLibrary.dll). Exe is using dll (references it). My main exe code is like that:

```
public class ApplicationSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting]
    [DefaultSettingValue(null)]
    public Settings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return ((Settings)this["Settings"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["Settings"] = value;
        }
    }

    [UserScopedSetting]
    [DefaultSettingValue(null)]
    public LibrarySettings LibrarySettings
    {
        get
        {
            return ((LibrarySettings)this["LibrarySettings"]);
        }
        set
        {
            this["LibrarySettings"] = value;
        }
    }  
}

public class Settings
{
    public string FirstValue { get; set; }
    public string LastValue { get; set; }
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Settings settings = new Settings {FirstValue = "1", LastValue = "2"};
    LibrarySettings librarySettings = new LibrarySettings { LibrarySettings1Value = "1", LibrarySettings2Value = "2" };

    ApplicationSettings applicationSettings  = new ApplicationSettings {Settings =  settings, LibrarySettings =  librarySettings};
    applicationSettings.Save();
}
```

And MyLibrary.dll code is:

```
public class LibrarySettings
{
    public string LibrarySettings1Value { get; set; }
    public string LibrarySettings2Value { get; set; }
}
```

It's important for me to use pre-built xmlSerialization dlls for my project. So, then I add **“$(FrameworkSDKDir)\Bin\sgen” /a:"$(TargetPath)" /force** Post-built event command line (both for exe and dll). Then I got two xmlSerialization dll on my release directory: **(BugTest.XmlSerializers.dll and MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll)**

I start my application and start process monitor. Everything is ok and my application settings are saved succesfully. And I see that csc.exe (run time compiler) never run during serialization. It's also important for me to making Xmlserialization without csc.exe. So everything is well for me.

Also on my project I've to merge BugTest.exe and Mylibrary.dll. **So I use ILMerge and merged BugTest.exe and MyLibrary.dll**. Output is BugTest.exe. (BugTest.XmlSerializers.dll and MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll are not merged.) When I run and click save button of this merged BugTest.exe, saving application data to file is possible again but process monitor screen alert me that this xmlserialization maked by csc.exe. BugTest.XmlSerializers.dll and MyLibrary.XmlSerializers.dll are in the same directory with BugTest.exe but **why my application using csc.exe for XmlSerialization this time instead of XmlSerializers.dlls ?
How can I force merged executable to use XmlSerializers.dlls ?**

> NOTE: Because of OOP design, I shouldn't carry LibrarySettings class codes from MyLibrary.dll to the BugTest.exe codes.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this problem by changing order of some processes.

If I compile the project without generating XMLSerialization dlls and then merge BugTest.exe and MyLibrary.dll as a new BugTest.exe and then generate BugTest.XmlSerialization.dll from this new BugTest.exe (using sgen) then my application works perfectly.

This post http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/2009/11/xmlserializers-moduleversionid-ilmerge.html is very useful for my solution.